# Moment.js.get weekdays as array with keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Currently in moment.js there is function `moment.weekdays()` which returns you the array like: `["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"]`

The issue for me that it does not have keys.

I've thought about something like this, but not quite sure if it's correct solution:

```
const array = moment.weekdays()
const newArr2 = array.map(v => Object.assign(v, {isActive: true}))
```

The result which I wish to get:

```
[["0", "Sunday"], ["1", "Monday"] ["2", "Tuesday"], ["3", "Wednesday"], ["4", "Thursday"], ["5", "Friday"], ["6", "Saturday"]]
```

Comment: What keys do you need?

Comment: Those should be numbers from 0-6 where 0 is Sunday

Comment: The key is the index: `array[today.getDay()]`

Comment: I've updated the question with the preview of result which I wish to get.

Comment: RubyMine added `isActive` automatically, so i do not have any clue. It's not used at all from my side. Well, I'm making dropdown where i should pass key as value to send it to a database, as i do not see any other option how to get key from just a string :)

Comment: What dropdown? A select? I can map you a select if you need

Comment: Yep, you're right. Select :)

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update after new information - Note I take your request literally although I think you have an X/Y problem

*The result I wish to get is [["0", "Sunday"], ["1", "Monday"] ["2", "Tuesday"], ["3", "Wednesday"], ["4", "Thursday"], ["5", "Friday"], ["6", "Saturday"]]*

```js
const array = moment.weekdays()
const newArr2 = array.map((v,i) => [String(i),v])
console.log(newArr2)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

A select:

```
populateOptions(options) {
  return moment.weekdays().map((option, index) => (
    <option key={index} value={option}>{option}</option>
  ));
}
```

old answer:

```
array[today.getDay()]
```

or do you mean something like this

```js
const today = moment();
const dow = today.day();

const array = moment.weekdays()
const newArr2 = array.map(v => ({[v]: { isActive: true}}))
console.log(newArr2[dow])
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js" integrity="sha512-qTXRIMyZIFb8iQcfjXWCO8+M5Tbc38Qi5WzdPOYZHIlZpzBHG3L3by84BBBOiRGiEb7KKtAOAs5qYdUiZiQNNQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: You can use today.day() to set `selected` if you need